# Creating an online CMD/Terminal using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cmd

I would like to deploy a CMD/Terminal for a website using javascript. A CMD maybe just for running python and other basic commands. How should I go about doing so? Are there any examples? And is JavaScript the best way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Termlib](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/) is what you are looking for I guess. It provides a "Terminal" object and you can extend it according to your requirement.

Demos could be found [here](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/multiterm_test.html)

Answer (score 1):

Examples: Anyterm, Ajaxterm

You could also use ssh if your firewall / site setup will allow it.

Or you could use vnc to get gui access, if you run a gui on your servers.

I think the best way to get access is either ssh or vnc. If you use Windows servers then remote desktop.

The main reason I could see for using a javascript based in browser UI would be if a firewall between you and the server won't allow ssh and you don't want to or can't configure vnc on the machines involved.

Finally, a really nice looking example of this kind of access on a web site is at...
[koding.com](http://koding.com/)
I saw these guys at the SFJS Meetup a few months back.